# Wrongly closing my jQuery script?

Tags: jquery

```
<script>
$("document").ready(function() {
  $("em#tinkatag").hover(function() {
    $(".tag.tinka").fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
  });
  $(".tag.tinka").hover(function() {
    $(".tag.tinka").toggle(
      function() {
        $("em#tinkatag").css("color","gray");
      },
      function () {
        $("em#tinkatag").css("color","red");
      }
    );
  )};
)};
</script>
```

I am trying to import this script into my wordpress site.
I am pretty sure I am doing it right and yet I keep getting this error.

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

What am I doing wrong? THank you for your time !

Comment: You should really try to indent your code for readability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last two closing "brackets" are in the wrong order:

```
)};
```

should be

```
});
```

because the `}` belongs to the function definition and the `)` to the function call.

Comment: Wow, this has been so confusing for me (I'm working with large codes), must have been looking over it over and over again.. thank you for the awesome help man!!

Answer (score 1):

Change )}; to }); on the last two lines.

Comment: Wow, this has been so confusing for me (I'm working with large codes), must have been looking over it over and over again.. thank you for the awesome help man!!

Answer (score 0):

Check `});`

Make it `)};`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("em#tinkatag").hover(function() {
    $(".tag.tinka").fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
  });
  $(".tag.tinka").hover(function() {
    $(".tag.tinka").toggle(
      function() {
        $("em#tinkatag").css("color","gray");
      },
      function () {
        $("em#tinkatag").css("color","red");
      }
    );
  });
});
```